# Connection error in Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm trying to connect to my database on MySQL, with Sequel:

```
require "bundler"
Bundler.require

DB = Sequel.connect ({
    adapter: "mysql2",
    host: "localhost",
    port: "3306",
    user: "root@localhost",
    password: "1234",
    database: "sequel_demo"
})
```

I get this error:

```
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.2-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/clien
t.rb:87:in `connect': Mysql2::Error: Access denied for user 'A2'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Your DB doesn't have a `A2` user?

Comment: I solved this, created new user for mysql, with all permissions.